# How to add integers from one list to another in ascending order?

Tags: python

Assuming:

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [11,12,13,14,15]

How do I make it such that:

x+y = z

In that z is: 
z = [12,14,16,18,20]

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not show any effort to solve the issue.

Comment: I apologise if I used the wrong tag for this. I'm still new to this site and I had the impression that I could get some programming help from this online community - or at least, I've seen people asking questions like this. I could write the mentioned question using a for loop but I was hoping for something out there would allow me to execute this out in the shortest way possible as I am writing a time sensitive script. But it looks like someone here has answered for me already, so sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use zip and list comprehension.

```
z = [a+b for a,b in zip(x,y)]
```